# Call multiple functions but one after another with each onClick of same button in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, if-statement

I have a button with a click event called `handleCount()`. I have 3 functions, `fun1()`, `fun2()`, `fun3()`. I'm calling `fun1()`, `fun2()`, `fun3()` in `handleCount()` based on `count` value.

If `count` value is 0 then `fun1` should be called, if count value is 1 then `fun1()` and `fun2()` should be called and if count value is 2 then `fun1()`, `fun2()`, `fun3()` should be called and its working as expected.

The issue is that I want them to be called one after another with each click like when `count === 2` then `fun1()` should be called first and then on 2 click `fun2()` should be called and for 3rd click `fun3()` should be called.

How can I achieve this? I would like to know logic to implement this.

Note I'm not incrementing/decrementing `count` value because I get `count` value from an API.

```js
var count = 2;

const function1 = () => {
  console.log("Function one");
}

const function2 = () => {
  console.log("Function two")
}

const function3 = () => {
  console.log("Function three")
}

const handleCount = () => {
  if (count === 0) {
    function1();
  }
  if (count === 1) {
    function1();
    function2();
  }
  if (count === 2) {
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
  }
}

return (
  <>
   <button onClick={handleCount}></button>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly at count === 2 you want to call each of 3 functions.
So you can do it as simple as it is possible.

```
if(count > -1) fn1()
if(count > 0) fn2()
if(count > 1) fn3()
```

Comment: Thanks @programmer for your response. When count ===2 then fun1() fun2() fun3() should be called but one by one when i click button not all at once.

Comment: What do you mean by "one by one" ? Do you need to wait for some data that fn1() will return?

Comment: I mean, When i click button with handleCount() <button onClick={handleCount}>Click</button> then handleCount = () =>{ fun1(); fun2(); fun()3; } will call three functions. But what im trying is "when i click button first time fun1() should be called and on clicking button for 2nd time, fun2() should be called". I need to understand logic to implement this.

Comment: so my implementation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a switch case.
(omitting the break you tell the code to not exit the switch)

```
switch(count) {
  case 3:
    function3();
    
  case 2:
    function2();

  default:
     function1();
}

// count = 3 --> function3();
// count = 1 --> function1(); function2(); function3();
```

Comment: Thanks @voidbrain,I have doubt like Im getting count value from api. value is just 0,1,2 When i use switch case then count finds case number and condition is satisfied which is equivalent to count value. For example if count ===2 then case 2 will be executed right ? then only function2() will be callled.

Comment: No, rules in switch case are just cascading, the variable is not incremental, 
This is way I omitted the break rules

try this:

const count = 3;
switch(count) {
  case 4:
    console.log(4)
 case 3:
    console.log(3)
  case 2:
    console.log(2)
  default:
    console.log(1)
}

Comment: Okay let me try with this logic. Once again thanks @voidbrain

Comment: I tried with switch @voidbrain. getting same output like using if statement which i tried before. When i click button, all 3 cases will be called at once. But Im trying to call them one after one click. First click = call => fun1(), for 2nd click = call => fun2(), for 3rd click = call => func3().

Comment: Ok, so.... ad break. Am I missing something?

switch(count) {
  case 3:
    function3();
    break;
  case 2:
    function2();
  break;
  case 1:
     function1();
  break;
}

Comment: Okay i with break

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to call a single function each time you click the button. The first time you click the button it will call a function corresponding to a count you get from the API. Subsequent clicks will call the next numbered function.

To do this I would keep track of how many times the button has been clicked.

```js
    const fn1 = () => console.log("1")
    const fn2 = () => console.log("2")
    const fn3 = () => console.log("3")
    
    
    const count = 3
    let clicks = 0
    const functions = [fn1,fn2,fn3]
    const functionsHighestIndex = functions.length - 1
    function handleClick(){
        let countWithClicks = count - 1 + clicks % functions.length
        const indexOfFunctionToCall = countWithClicks > functionsHighestIndex ? countWithClicks - functions.length : countWithClicks
        functions[indexOfFunctionToCall]()
        clicks +=1
      }
      
      const button = document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```